# How to read file line by line by CRLF

Tags: java, string, file, newline

I have the following file:

[image]

and following code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File(file.txt)));
scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n");
int i = 0;
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    scanner.nextLine();
    i++;
}
System.out.println(i);
```

It returns `5`.

expected result: `2`.

What do I wrong?

I want to split by CRLF only (not LF).

Comment: `"`\x0D\x0A`"` should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `scanner.next()` to invoke the delimiter specified.

`scanner.nextLine()` will use `\n` (exact pattern is `\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]`) as delimiter, hence the length is 5.

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    scanner.next();
    i++;
}
```